# Running all rows in a column through a Python function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python called `df_test_geo` that looks as such:

```
{'userid': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}, 'text_string': {0: 'I live in Miami and work in software', 1: 'Chicago, IL', 2: 'Dog Mom in Cincinnati', 3: 'Accountant at @EY/Baltimore', 4: 'World traveler but I call Atlanta home', 5: 'Lover of dogs!', 6: 'Working in Orlando. From Korea.'}}
```

I am then using the following package: `from geotext import GeoText`

If I run the following:

```
places = GeoText(df_test_geo.text_string[0])

places.cities
```

It correctly returns:

```
['Miami']
```

But what if I want to capture all the responses by creating a new column called `location` where it stores the responses from the above code, but for all rows in the `text_string` column?

So the `location` output would look like this (in order): `Miami, Chicago, Cincinnati, Baltimore, Atlanta, '', Orlando`

The spot between Atlanta and Orlando is empty because there is no city in `text_string` so the package won't return anything.

When I run:

```
places = GeoText(df_test_geo.text_string)

places.cities
```

It returns the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: `places = [GeoText(x).cities for x in df_test_geo.text_string]`

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't quite solve my ask. How would I append that on to the original dataframe?

Comment: `df_test_geo['places'] = [GeoText(x)...]`?